# How do I redirect a specific URL to subfolder in a Laravel CMS?

Tags: .htaccess

I have Laravel installed in [myoffice.com.sg](https://myoffice.com.sg) and it seems to redirect all my visits to /public for Laravel CMS to handle.

This is .htaccess for the primary folder.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I am hoping to have a subfolder (eg /agency) that is Wordpress/HTML, which would not be handled by Laravel CMS. For example - visits to [www.myoffice.com.sg](http://www.myoffice.com.sg) will be going to Laravel, while [www.myoffice.com.sg/agency](http://www.myoffice.com.sg/agency) will be going to Wordpress or HTML.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I found a code that seems to work.

```
# Route any request begining with 'agency/' to agency subfolder
RewriteRule ^agency/(.*)$ agency/$1 [L]
# Anything else goes to Laravel
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Seems to work. In case anyone needs.

However, it seems like only myoffice.com.sg/agency/index.php works, not myoffice.com.sg/agency

Is there any solution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).